# Why does the iframe tag have a closing tag?

Tags: html, iframe

Why does the iframe tag have a closing tag?
Since there is no content expected between the two tags (the content is always empty), why is the iframe tag not unique, like the embed tag, link tags,  meta tags (img, br, hr, etc.)?
The computer language should not be essential?
I have not found an answer in the w3c site: [The `iframe`element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/PR-html51-20160915/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-iframe-element)
Sorry for the stupid question.
Thanks to anyone who answers.
Juri

Comment: From your own link: *"In legacy user agents that do not support iframe elements, the contents would be parsed as markup that could act as fallback content."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since it is not expected any content between the two tags (the content is always empty)

There is. You are expected to put alternative content to be displayed in browsers which can't, or won't, load the framed content.

(At least, that was the case before HTML 5, which seems to have forgotten about that feature, but still needs to support existing implementations in browsers).

Comment: like "alt" attribute?

Comment: Yes (although `alt` gets used in more situations, such as for screen readers).

Comment: thank you.
although I think that, perhaps, the alt attribute in the only start tag would be better than an additional (end) tag

Comment: @Juri — Then you couldn't have markup (such as headings and links)

Comment: Very true :-)
But this did not stop to remove the end tag in img and input tags (which in fact have the alt attribute). Anyway, thanks again , I understood why.